# Ordinal encoding of column in polars

Tags: python-polars

I would like to do an ordinal encoding of a column. Pandas has the nice and convenient method of `pd.factorize()`, however, I would like to achieve the same in polars.

```
 df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [5, 8, 10], "b": ["hi", "hello", "hi"]})
┌─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b     │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 5   ┆ hi    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8   ┆ hello │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10  ┆ hi    │
└─────┴───────┘
```

desired result:

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join with a dummy `DataFrame` that contains the unique values and the ordinal encoding you are interested in:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [5, 8, 10], "b": ["hi", "hello", "hi"]})

unique = df.select(
    pl.col("b").unique(maintain_order=True)
).with_row_count(name="ordinal")

df.join(unique, on="b")
```

Or you could "misuse" the fact that categorical values are backed by `u32` integers.

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.col("b").cast(pl.Categorical).to_physical().alias("ordinal")
)
```

Both methods output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ a   ┆ b     ┆ ordinal │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ u32     │
╞═════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 5   ┆ hi    ┆ 0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8   ┆ hello ┆ 1       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 10  ┆ hi    ┆ 0       │
└─────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: nice - the second one is similar to the pandas pattern `df['b'].astype('category').cat.codes`

Perhaps polars `.cat` could also have this `.codes` property? (I'd happily make a PR if this would be welcome)

Comment: That's why I called it "misuse". We don't give any guarantees about the physical backing of the categoricals. They should be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: OK, thanks - would there be no other way you'd be open to to have `.cat.codes`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it although I doubt it's better than the dummy Dataframe from @ritchie46

```
df.with_columns([pl.col('b').unique().list().alias('uniq'),
                pl.col('b').unique().list().arr.eval(pl.element().rank()).alias('uniqid')]).explode(['uniq','uniqid']).filter(pl.col('b')==pl.col('uniq')).select(pl.exclude('uniq')).with_column(pl.col('uniqid')-1)
```

There's almost certainly a way to improve this but basically it creates a new column called `uniq` which is a list of all the unique values of the column as well as `uniqid` which (I think, and seems to be) the 1-index based order of the values.  It then explodes those creating a row for ever value in `uniq` and then filters out the ones rows that don't equal the column `b`.  Since `rank` gives the 1-index (rather than 0-index) you have to subtract `1` and exclude the `uniq` column that we don't care about since it's the same as `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not important you could use `.rank(method="dense")`

```
>>> df.select(pl.all().rank(method="dense") - 1)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

If it is - you could:

```
>>> (
...    df.with_row_count()
...      .with_columns([
...         pl.col("row_nr").first()
...           .over(col)
...           .rank(method="dense")
...           .alias(col) - 1
...         for col in df.columns
...      ])
...      .drop("row_nr")
... )
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```